# Xml inline valdiation in .Net5.0 does not find xsd

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, .net-5, .net-4.7.2

I want to validate some XML file agianst an XSD file.

I was forced to change the framework from .Net4.7.2 to .Net5.0.

This is the code to write and validate the XML file:

```
namespace XmlValidation
{
    class Programm
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string file = "test.xml";

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, IndentChars = "    " }))
            {
                new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass)).Serialize(xmlWriter, new MyClass() { Property1 = "Content" });
            }

            List<string> messages = new();
            XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new()
            {
                ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
                ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema
                | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation
                | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings
            };
            xmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler((sender, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
            });

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(file, xmlReaderSettings))
            {
                while (reader.Read()) ;
            }

        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        [XmlAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
        public string xmlShemaFile = "schema0.xsd";

        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I get the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema0.xsd">
    <Property1>Content</Property1>
</MyClass>
```

and the xsd is in the same directory as the test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MyClass" type="MyClass" />
  <xs:complexType name="MyClass">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Property1" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Property2" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The result is:

```
"Could not find schema information for the element 'MyClass'."
"Could not find schema information for the element 'Property1'."
```

The same works fine with .NetFramework 4.7.2.

```
"Der Inhalt des Elements 'MyClass' ist unvollständig. Erwartet wurde die Liste der möglichen Elemente: 'Property2'."
```

Why does this not work with .Net5.0?

Comment: For diagnostics, you could try adding an `XmlResolver` to the `XmlReaderSettings` and seeing whether it gets called, and how.

Comment: Yes, I think starting from some version (.NET 4.8) you need to create and provide and explicit XmlUrlResolver() to load other documents like a schema.

Comment: Hmm, the docs says the default is null since 4.5.2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.xmlresolver?view=net-5.0 but nevertheless try setting the resolver.

Comment: I don't know why you just don't use Net and Target 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Mickel Kay* and *Martin Honnen* mentioned in the comments, adding an XmlResolver did the trick:

```
XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new()
{
    ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
    ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema
    | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation
    | XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings,
    XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver(),
};
```